# Spring OAuth (2) clustered session serialization issue

Tags: java, session, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using successfully Spring OAuth2 with Google in a Spring Boot application and now the time has come to make the application high available (for start to have more than 1 instance). Spring OAuth by default creates a session so not to work against the framework the sensible think is to use clustered sessions.
For a first proof of concept i choosed Redis as a key value store to persist the session.

**The setup is done but i now have an issue: the Spring OAuth creates a very heavy session with OAuthRestTemplate, Resources and even the Request which is hard to serialize.**

Has anybody found a solution for this ?

Comment: What do you mean specifically by "hard to serialize"?

Comment: By hard to serialize i meaning there are complex objects in the session which are put by the Spring OAuth2 (ex: like OAuth2RestTemplate or HttpRequest ) and by default they should not be saved. More because how Spring Works i can little influence the serialization process but this looks like a hack then a good usage